# Class without Encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding encapsulation in Java.  What I know is that encapsulation allows for information hiding (using private variables) from anywhere else in the program.  But, could anyone show me **how** creating a class with public data fields could cause problems?  I'm not understanding how the data is hidden if the classes have getter and setter methods provided.

```
   public class Student{

       private int id;
       private String name;
       private int grade;

  public Student(){
  }

  public Student(int id; String name, int grade){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.grade = grade;
  }

  public int getId(){
       return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id){
       this.id = id;
  }

  //more code

  }
```

Comment: Your questions way too broad and might get closed. Just imagine if your wallet is accessible to all then what kind of issues you may face? Its on similar lines

Comment: By the very definition of `public`.  The moment you declared anything public it becomes a part of your class' contract and you have to maintain it for ever and ever.

Comment: I'm really new at programming as a whole, I'm just not understanding how making the instance variables private makes them inaccessible when theres getter and setter methods @Lokesh

Comment: @user3806226: Spend some time going through books/examples, you will have better understanding. If you ask more precise questions then people will be able to help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example where a public field can make its class completely unreliable. An alternative private version can guarantee that its information is always valid, and is untouchable by undesirable actors.

Public field class (insecure):

```
class VeryImportantCounterPublic  {
   public int currentCount;
   public VeryImportantCounterPublic(int initial_count)  {
      currentCount = initial_count;
   }
   public void incrementCount()  {
      currentCount++;
   }
   public int getCurrentCount()  {
      return  currentCount;
   }
}
```

Private field class (secure):

```
class VeryImportantCounterPrivate  {
   private int currentCount;
   public VeryImportantCounterPrivate(int initial_count)  {
      currentCount = initial_count;
   }
   public void incrementCount()  {
      currentCount++;
   }
   public int getCurrentCount()  {
      return  currentCount;
   }
}
```

Main:

```
public class CounterTest  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      VeryImportantCounterPublic counter = new VeryImportantCounterPublic(3);
      counter.incrementCount();
      counter.incrementCount();
      counter.incrementCount();

      //Should not be able to do this!!
      //But it's a public field, so you can  :(
      counter.currentCount = -203847382;

      System.out.println("[PUBLIC] Current count is " + counter.getCurrentCount());


      VeryImportantCounterPrivate counter2 = new VeryImportantCounterPrivate(3);
      counter2.incrementCount();
      counter2.incrementCount();
      counter2.incrementCount();

      //Can't do this. Compiler error:
      //counter2.currentCount = -203847382;

      System.out.println("[PRIVATE] Current count is " + counter2.getCurrentCount());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[PUBLIC] Current count is -203847382
[PRIVATE] Current count is 6
```

---

Full source:

```
public class CounterTest  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      VeryImportantCounterPublic counter = new VeryImportantCounterPublic(3);
      counter.incrementCount();
      counter.incrementCount();
      counter.incrementCount();
      counter.currentCount = -203847382;
      System.out.println("[PUBLIC] Current count is " + counter.getCurrentCount());


      VeryImportantCounterPrivate counter2 = new VeryImportantCounterPrivate(3);
      counter2.incrementCount();
      counter2.incrementCount();
      counter2.incrementCount();
      //Can't do this. Compiler error:
      //counter2.currentCount = -203847382;
      System.out.println("[PRIVATE] Current count is " + counter2.getCurrentCount());
   }
}


class VeryImportantCounterPublic  {
   public int currentCount;
   public VeryImportantCounterPublic(int initial_count)  {
      currentCount = initial_count;
   }
   public void incrementCount()  {
      currentCount++;
   }
   public int getCurrentCount()  {
      return  currentCount;
   }
}

class VeryImportantCounterPrivate  {
   private int currentCount;
   public VeryImportantCounterPrivate(int initial_count)  {
      currentCount = initial_count;
   }
   public void incrementCount()  {
      currentCount++;
   }
   public int getCurrentCount()  {
      return  currentCount;
   }
}
```

Comment: So the only difference between the classes is changing from public (insecure) to private (secure).  When you wrote this  (counter.currentCount = -203847382) you had the capability to make this change just because your variable was public? @aliteralmind

Comment: Yes. Making a field public is generally a bad thing, although there are some unusual situations where it might be reasonable. It's not just that the private version forbids you from doing it, it's that you are informed of this *during compilation*, not during runtime (which is by definition, after compilation). You always want to know about errors as soon as possible, and making fields private is one among many tools to help with this. Compilation errors are *always* better than runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

The term 'Information Hiding' doesn't necessarily have to infer that the security of the information is at stake.  But to touch on the security topic first, in the tremendous book "Code Complete" version 2, Steve McConnell writes:

"Exposing member data is a violation of encapsulation and limits your control over the abstraction."

The key insight here, is that you loose control of the interaction between those using your code and how you intended the code to act.  Consider this scenario given your example code: you are given a requirement/constraint from your boss/client/teacher that says: do some error checking on the id field to make certain that it is within a bounds (maybe only positive numbers are allowed).  How would you implement the requirement to be sure that whenever someone gets the id back that it follows that requirement?

Here is an example implementation of that requirement:

```
public void setId(int id){
   if(id < 0) {
       this.id = 0;
   } else {
       this.id = id;
   }
}
```

This implementation allows you to be certain that the id field is set appropriately given the requirement, which allows you to tell the people that are using the code that the id will always be positive.  Unfortunately, when someone else is using your code, they have the capability of directly referencing the member variable and setting it like so if it is public:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.id = -1;
```

And when someone is sitting down at an IDE (even possibly yourself while continuing the implementing the code) how will they know not to use the above method of setting the id field?  The best way to control the access to the field is by allowing only one entry point to it.
Perhaps the most important aspect of 'Information Hiding' though, is the fact that if you control the access to the member variables through accessors and mutators, you can make implementation changes without the user ever being the wiser.  Consider this scenario: your boss/client/teacher now asks you to encrypt the id field into an alpha-numeric string without effecting the user's of your code that are already using Version 1 of your software.  If you had allowed direct access to the member variable, then you couldn't change the internal representation of the id field, ever, without potentially breaking the code that people may have already written on top of yours.
They may be doing something like this:

```
 Student student = new Student();
 int currentId = student.id;
 int idWithOffset = currentId + 100;
```

What would happen if you suddenly needed/wanted to make id a String or an Id object?  If you had kept id as private, you could make these changes as needed, and write code in the setter/getter that handles the conversion logic, and the user's code would never need to change.
My final (and personal favorite reason) why 'Information Hiding' such as making members private, helps in reducing problems, is that it removes one more detail of the code that would otherwise need to be floating around in UML charts, your brain, Javadocs, etc...  Information hiding helps abstraction so that you can think about all the components and players inside the class when you are working on THAT class, and don't have to keep it in your brain when working on OTHER classes.

 Cheers. 
Also, a great reference for question like these in the Java language is "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch (2nd edition).

Comment: Good points beyond the security aspect. +1

Answer (score 2):

Getters and Setters create a `looser coupling`.

Let say that you hire someone to carry your wallet for you.

If the location of this wallet is `public` than you know where your employee caries it.  You can grab it directly and, so this person has to carry it always in the same pocket.

If it's location is `private`, you no longer are allowed to take the wallet. You need to ask for it (using a `getter` method).  Given that your employee by contract still has to give it to you, he does not have to let you know where exactly he keeps it. So he can start putting it in any place that is comfortable for him - in another pocket or in his bag - without breaking the contract. As a result you still can have your wallet any time you need it, but you do not have to know where it's being carried.

Comment: so this is what they mean by "black boxing" when they refer to encapsulation?  You know it's there but you don't know the details?

Comment: @user3806226 - Right. But it's better to say you **do not need** to know.